# Should I accept my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, best-practice

ENGLISH:

In stackoverflow it is simple. If something solved your problem, you can post it and check it as the accepted answer. However, in Portuguese — being it a Humanity, a language — there may always be one little misinformation, or something essential that could be added.

When “I share my knowledge” — self-answered questions — what are the criteria to accept my own? When it has X upvotes, after Y days, if I thoroughly researched the topic, if good reference was given, all of the aforementioned?

EM PORTUGUÊS:

Em stackoverflow é fácil, se algo sanou sua dúvida, você pode postá-lo e então aceitar a resposta. Todavia, em Português — sendo esse uma língua, uma Humanidade — sempre poderá haver uma ínfima desinformação, or algo essencial ao tópico que foi negligenciado.

Quando “compartilho meu conhecimento”,  — perguntas autorrespondidas — quais são os critérios para aceitar minha própria resposta? Com X upvotes, após Y dias, quando pesquisei o tópico intensivamente, quando apresentei boas referências críveis, todos os supramencionados?

Comment: In Portuguese Language is like stackoverflow, keep it simple ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for a few days (more than the 'usual' two, since Portuguese SE is not very busy) and if nothing better has been posted, do accept your own answer.

That has been the idea from (almost) [the beginning](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).